# Sort items per customer

Tags: excel, vba, invoice

I am making a tool in excel VBA to bulk create some kind of invoices to each customer. We are making LIVE streams and selling kids clothing, then we write all our orders to excel sheet. Example:
[orders list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4HwS.jpg)

Then we have to sort all those orders by customer (there are many of them) and create some kind of invoice for each customer. Example: ["invoice template"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvcPJ.jpg)

I use this code to bulk create those and download as pdfs.

```
Sub Create_PDF_Files()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim dsh As Worksheet
Dim tsh As Worksheet
Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet

Set dsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("uzsakymai")
Set tsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("lapukas")
Set setting_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")


Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = ""

Dim i As Integer
Dim File_Name As String

For i = 2 To dsh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.StatusBar = i - 1 & "/" & dsh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

tsh.Range("D1").Value = dsh.Range("C" & i).Value
tsh.Range("A4").Value = dsh.Range("B" & i).Value
tsh.Range("B4").Value = dsh.Range("A" & i).Value & " - " & dsh.Range("E" & i).Value
tsh.Range("P4").Value = dsh.Range("D" & i).Value

File_Name = dsh.Range("A" & i).Value & "(" & dsh.Range("C" & i).Value & "-" & dsh.Range("D" & i).Value & ").pdf"
tsh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, setting_Sh.Range("F4").Value & "\" & File_Name

Next i

Application.StatusBar = ""

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

But what it does is creating invoice for each item.
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xs2.jpg)

Any ideas how could I make it work for me as I want it to work?

---EDIT---

After ALeXceL answer, it seems to have some bugs. I changed my code to his code, and I see some progress in creating this program, but what it does, is it shows first item correctly, but all the other items are appearing starting on A24 cell. [EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U8so.jpg)

---EDIT---

IT WORKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "uzsakymai" is "orders", the 'data sheet' (dsh) and "lapukas" is the 'template' sheet (tsh), I did these changes, added some counters, in order to the logic flows the right way:

Important: before put this code to run you MUST classify the 'orders' table (dsh, or "uzsakymai") first by Name, then, by Size (as you wish, according to the images posted)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_PDF_Files()

    Dim Orders_sh As Worksheet
    Dim Template_sh As Worksheet
    Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim strKey_TheName As String
    Dim lngTemplate_A As Long
    Dim lngSumOfItems As Long
    Dim dblSumOfValues As Double
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Orders_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("uzsakymai")
    Set Template_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("lapukas")
    Set setting_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")


    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = ""

    Dim lngI As Long
    Dim File_Name As String

    'At this point, the Orders_sh worksheet should already have its fields properly sorted/ordered. (Name, then Size)
    lngI = 2
    Application.StatusBar = lngI - 1 & "/" & Orders_sh.Range("A11").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'a maximum of 10 items can be written here!
    Set oCell = Orders_sh.Range("A" & lngI) ' the initial cell

    Do
        strKey_TheName = UCase(Orders_sh.Range("C" & lngI).Value)
        lngSumOfItems = 0
        dblSumOfValues = 0

        Do
            Template_sh.Range("D1").Value = Orders_sh.Range("C" & lngI).Value
            lngTemplate_A = IIf(lngSumOfItems = 0, 4, Template_sh.Range("A10").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row)
            Template_sh.Range("A" & lngTemplate_A).Value = Orders_sh.Range("B" & lngI).Value
            Template_sh.Range("B" & lngTemplate_A).Value = Orders_sh.Range("A" & lngI).Value & " - " & Orders_sh.Range("E" & lngI).Value
            Template_sh.Range("P" & lngTemplate_A).Value = Orders_sh.Range("D" & lngI).Value
            
            lngSumOfItems = lngSumOfItems + 1
            dblSumOfValues = dblSumOfValues + Orders_sh.Range("D" & lngI).Value
            
            File_Name = lngSumOfItems & "(" & Orders_sh.Range("C" & lngI).Value & "-" & VBA.Round(dblSumOfValues, 0) & ").pdf"
            lngI = lngI + 1
            Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop Until strKey_TheName <> UCase(oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value)

        Template_sh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, setting_Sh.Range("F4").Value & "\" & File_Name
        Template_sh.Range("D1").Value = ""
        Template_sh.Range("A4:P10").ClearContents
    Loop Until Len(oCell.Value) = 0

    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It seems to have some bugs. I changed my code to your code, and I see some progress in creating this program, but what it does, is it shows first item correctly, but all the other items are appearing starting on A24 cell. I guess I can't upload a picture to comments, so I'll edit my question.

Comment: I've changed this piece of the code to: lngTemplate_A = IIf(lngSumOfItems = 0, 4, Template_sh.Range("A10").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row). This will limit the evaluation of the variable lngTemplate_A, due to layout limits on Template_sh (maximum is 10) <<< remember this limit.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is any chance that I could change some lines of code to create one pdf with all the invoices instead of separate pdfs for each customer? I need it for printing (because I print 2 invoices on 1 page and then cut it in half). Of course I can merge pdfs with some specific tools online, but it would be awesome to have that opportunity.